# What is the meaning of /** @docs-private */ in angular's typescript codebase?

Tags: angular, typescript

I was reading through some of the @angular/cdk code on GitHub and I am wondering what is the meaning of this "@docs-private" comment.

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/table/row.ts

[image]

````
 * Base class for the CdkHeaderRowDef and CdkRowDef that handles checking their columns inputs
 * for changes and notifying the table.
 */
@Directive()
export abstract class BaseRowDef implements OnChanges {
  /** The columns to be displayed on this row. */
  columns: Iterable<string>;

  /** Differ used to check if any changes were made to the columns. */
  protected _columnsDiffer: IterableDiffer<any>;

  constructor(
    /** @docs-private */ public template: TemplateRef<any>,
    protected _differs: IterableDiffers,
  ) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    // Create a new columns differ if one does not yet exist. Initialize it based on initial value
    // of the columns property or an empty array if none is provided.
    if (!this._columnsDiffer) {
      const columns = (changes['columns'] && changes['columns'].currentValue) || [];
      this._columnsDiffer = this._differs.find(columns).create();
      this._columnsDiffer.diff(columns);
    }
  }```
````

Comment: Not really a typescript thing, formatted comments like that are pretty much always directives to tools. Not sure which one in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

It's internal tooling for Angular docs

- https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/CODING_STANDARDS.md#access-modifiers

> Additionally, the @docs-private JsDoc annotation can be used to hide any symbol from the public API docs.

In GitHub you can do a `search` within the codebase - very handy for things like this